# python 3.5 create object in new process and manipulate by parent

Tags: python, object, queue, multiprocessing

I use python 3.5 64bits in Windows7 pro 64bits.

I want to create object in new process for use a multicore, but I want manipulate this object with parent process, is it possible ?

This is my code:

```
    import multiprocessing

class MyFancyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def fancyfancyfunction(self) :
        print "My name is so fancy : '%s'" %self.name

def worker(q):
    obj = MyFancyClass('Fancy fancy')
    q.put(obj)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(queue,))
    p.start()
    obj = queue.get()
    print obj.name
    obj.fancyfancyfunction()
    p.join()
```

My probleme is that my object (obj) not turn in other core of processor.

I want to create object in new process, and i want to run method of this object by parent process.

Actualy, my programm not run in multi-core, it's run in one core why ?

Comment: It's good I corrected

Comment: Please tell us what is not clarify ?